# Printing/modifying a specific member variable of a class object, whose class defines the type of elements the list(STL) contains

Tags: c++, list, stl

```
class pair
{
public:
    int a, b;
    pair(int tmp_a, int tmp_b)
    {
        a = tmp_a;
        b = tmp_b;
    }
};

int main()
{
    list<pair> l;
    l.push_back(pair(1,6));
    l.push_back(pair(2,7));
    l.push_back(pair(3,8));
    l.push_back(pair(4,9));
    l.push_back(pair(5,10));

    for (auto& pair_item : l/*std::list<pair>::iterator i = l.begin(); i != l.end(); i++*/) //Edited
    {
        // print/modify the member variables in the object that iterator i points to 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

(Ref. to the code)
The list has elements of the type pair. Suppose I wish to modify the elements(objects of type pair) in the list, for instance change `b` to `b` + `a`. How can I do such an operation?

Comment: Any particular reason you use the (still correct, but) old-style for loop, instead of a range for?

Comment: I'm not quite used to it yet. I've used range based loops on many occasions before but this particular occasion, it just didn't strike me. I guess I was engrossed more in the issue that I was having.

Comment: @PuneetSingh If you're having issues with your code, you should clearly state them in your question (verbatim error messages).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... for instance change `b` to `b + a`. How can I do such an operation?

You can do the following:

```
for(auto& pair_item : l) {
    pair_item.b += pair_item.a;
}
```

---

As for the observed problems in your example code:

```
for (list<int>::iterator i = l.begin(); i != l.end(); i++)
  // ^^^^^^^^^ Isn't matching `list<pair>`
{
    (*i).b += (*i).a; // Should do the operation you want
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistake. I intended to write `list<pair>` instead of `list<int>`.